# How to reload extension/distribution to activate classes

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I use a Typo3 distribution as template for a website. The distribution is already activated via the extension manager.

Now I added a user function within the "Classes" folder and call them via a typoscript user_func. The autoload handling ist described in the composer.json.

But the function seem not to work. I've read that I have to deactivate and then again activate the distribution in the extension manager for getting the functions loaded. Is there another way to get them run? Because of all the dependencies of my extension I would prefer not to deactivate it. Or is there something wrong with my functions? Thank you for your help!

Here are my codes:

Classes/own_classes.php

```
namespace My\Namespace;

class TestClass {

   public function doTheTest($content, $conf) {
       return '<!--' . $conf['txtout'] . '-->';
   }

}
```

Typoscript user func:

```
lib.testfunc = USER_INT
lib.testfunc {
   userFunc = My\Namespace\TestClass->doTheTest
   txtout = Hallo Welt
}
```

Comment: Did you run `composer dump` after changing the composer file?

Comment: No - where or how can I do this?

Comment: You need a shell for that.

Comment: I assume I have to do this directly on the webserver? Sorry, but my knowledge about this is not very well. Do I have to execute the dump even if I changed nothing in the composer file?

Comment: You need to dump the autoloader when creating new files and new namespaces. You can do this as well in the Install Tool of TYPO3.

Comment: Thank you! Now my test function works!